# Member value of Linklist changed unexpextedly

Tags: c++

---

Member value of Linklist changed unexpextedly.
When the program gets the definition of pointer of pointer(see codes I pasted below), member **val** of **second** element of **l2** changed.After debugging, I got that `"ListNode **tail;"` use the same address as second element of **l2**. 
Please help me find out the probelm and tell Why?

---

Linklist struct as below:

```
struct ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode *next;
      ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
}
```

piece of problem code as below:

```
  ListNode *addTwoNumbers(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
  ListNode *p1=l1;
  ListNode *p2=l2;

  ListNode *rst=new ListNode(-1);
  ListNode **tail;  /*accident happened after here*/
 *tail=rst;
     ...
  }
```

I can figure that `tail` not initialized result in this bug. But I'v no idea what is go on.

Comment: It seems function addTwoNumbers does not make a sense.:)

Comment: other part are ignored . The function do the work that add two number that each digit is represented by element of linkList .

Comment: @shylonezeng can you show the entire function for `addTwoNumbers`.  The `ListNode **tail;` does not seem to make sense just based on what you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the following lines of code

```
ListNode **tail;  /*accident happened after here*/
*tail=rst;
```

is that you have not allocated memory for `tail` yet you are dereferencing it.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
ListNode **tail = &rst;
```

Comment: You are right ! I know how to make it work in correct way. But how can unallocated tail take the memery of defined object.

Comment: @shylonezeng, it can't. That's the problem with your current code.

Comment: `rst` is a local variable so `ListNode **tail = &rst;` seems quite dangerous,